# Update hash url in address bar when using smooth scroll and add active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I am using the smooth scroll technique from here.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-197181

```
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
                || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                   if (target.length) {
                     $('html,body').animate({
                         scrollTop: target.offset().top -104
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

It works perfectly for one-page site navigation except the browser's address bar never updates with the correct hash url. For example, loading domain.com and clicking a link to domain.com#foo goes to the section id foo, but the address bar still has domain.com as the URL (no #foo at the end).

Does anyone know how I can get the URL to add the hash automatically as the user navigates through the page?

I would also like to add an active class to the navigation bar in order to highlight which section id the user is on. Therefore, when they click the link to `#foo` in the nav, `class="active"` will automatically be added. Additionally, when they scroll away to another section, it will then be removed.

I appreciate any help you can give me. JQuery is not my strong suit, so I'm pretty much flying blind when it comes to modifying existing code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waypoints?

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('#waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
    }
});
```

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/